# Buttons not showing in design time in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio-3.1

Layout Code is like this.

**Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Activities.SocialMediaLogin.GoogleLogin">

    <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_Gmail_SignIn"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_sign_out_GMail"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Log Out"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_GMail_RevokeAccess"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Revoke Access"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Due to some reasons it always shows only Revoke Access button and hides the Sign Out button. Below is the screenshot. Am I missing anything?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's because your revoke button is overlapping your Logout button. To show that you need to set constraint properties of these views